# Does CrossValidator in PySpark distribute the execution?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, parameters, pyspark

I am playing with Machine Learning in PySpark and am using a RandomForestClassifier. I have used Sklearn till now. I am using CrossValidator to tune the parameters and get the best model. A sample code taken from Spark's website is below.

From what I have been reading, I do not understand whether spark distributes the parameter tuning as well or it is the same as in case of GridSearchCV of Sklearn.

Any help would really appreciated.

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, Tokenizer
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder

# Prepare training documents, which are labeled.
training = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
    (1, "b d", 0.0),
    (2, "spark f g h", 1.0),
    (3, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0),
    (4, "b spark who", 1.0),
    (5, "g d a y", 0.0),
    (6, "spark fly", 1.0),
    (7, "was mapreduce", 0.0),
    (8, "e spark program", 1.0),
    (9, "a e c l", 0.0),
    (10, "spark compile", 1.0),
    (11, "hadoop software", 0.0)
], ["id", "text", "label"])

# Configure an ML pipeline, which consists of tree stages: tokenizer, hashingTF, and lr.
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="words")
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(), outputCol="features")
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, lr])

# We now treat the Pipeline as an Estimator, wrapping it in a CrossValidator instance.
# This will allow us to jointly choose parameters for all Pipeline stages.
# A CrossValidator requires an Estimator, a set of Estimator ParamMaps, and an Evaluator.
# We use a ParamGridBuilder to construct a grid of parameters to search over.
# With 3 values for hashingTF.numFeatures and 2 values for lr.regParam,
# this grid will have 3 x 2 = 6 parameter settings for CrossValidator to choose from.
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(hashingTF.numFeatures, [10, 100, 1000]) \
    .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.01]) \
    .build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                          numFolds=2)  # use 3+ folds in practice

# Run cross-validation, and choose the best set of parameters.
cvModel = crossval.fit(training)
```

Comment: any hints or if the question is not clear, please advise

Answer (score 5):

**Spark 2.3+**

[SPARK-21911](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21911) included parallel model fitting. The level of parallelism is controlled with `parallelism` `Param`.

**Spark < 2.3**

It does not. Cross validation is implemented as a plain [nested `for` loop](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7047f49f45406be3b4a9b0aa209b3021621392ca/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py#L258-L269):

```
for i in range(nFolds):
    ...
    for j in range(numModels):
        ...
```

Only the process of training individual models is distributed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. As answered by other users, the process is not parralelized is a serial operation. However, there is a spark_sklearn module that could be used for this grid search which distributes it but it does not distribute the model building. So that's the tradeoff.

Here's the code using spark_sklearn GridSearchCV

```
%pyspark

"""
DATA - https://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/20newsgroups/mini_newsgroups.tar.gz
METHOD 1 - USING GRIDSEARCH CV FROM SPARK_SKLEARN MODULE BY DATABRICKS
DOCUMENTATION - https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/08/auto-scaling-scikit-learn-with-apache-spark.html
THIS IS DISTRIBUTED OPERATION AS MENTIONED ON THE WEBSITE
"""
from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF,StopWordsRemover,IDF,Tokenizer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StringType, StructType
from pyspark.ml.feature import IndexToString, StringIndexer
from spark_sklearn.converter import Converter
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline as S_Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as S_RandomForestClassifier

path = 's3://sparkzepellin/mini_newsgroups//*'
news = sc.wholeTextFiles(path)
print "Toal number of documents = ",news.count()

# print 5 samples
news.takeSample(False,5, 1)

# Using sqlContext createa dataframe
schema = ["id", "text", "topic"]
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field in schema]
schema = StructType(fields)

# Applying the schema decalred above as an RDD
newsgroups = news.map(lambda (localPath, text): (localPath.split("/")[-1], text, localPath.split("/")[-2]))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(newsgroups, schema)

df_new = StringIndexer(inputCol="topic", outputCol="label").fit(df).transform(df)

# Build a pipeline with tokenier, hashing TF, IDF, and finally a RandomForest
tokenizer = Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")
hashingTF = HashingTF().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
idf = IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")

pipeline=Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, idf])
data = pipeline.fit(df_new).transform(df_new)

# Using Converter, convert to pandas dataframe (numpy)
# to run on distributed sklearn using spark_sklearn package
converter = Converter(sc)
new_df = Converter.toPandas(data.select(data.features.alias("text"), "label"))

# Sklearn pipeline
s_pipeline = S_Pipeline([
            ('rf', S_RandomForestClassifier())
        ])

# Random parameters
parameters = {
    'rf__n_estimators': (10, 20),
    'rf__max_depth': (2, 10)
}

# Run GridSearchCV using the above defined parameters on the pipeline created
gridSearch = GridSearchCV(sc, s_pipeline, parameters)
GS = gridSearch.fit(new_df.text.values, new_df.rating.values)
```

Another way of doing this would be to use the map method to parallelize the operation and get back the metric such as accuracy.

Comment: This solution isn't good. It parallelizes CV but not the fit. You can parallelize one of the two processes : learning or cross validation.